# How to Check who is calling the WCF Windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication

I have created a WCF service that is hosted using windows service.

The windows service is running under LocalSystem under services.msc

I only want to allow accept requests from my asp.net UI users who are part of dmain's user group?
Eventually we will have multiple UIs and I want to not write security checks code in the UI.

How do I check who is making the call so I could do something like:

```
if (incomingUserGroup != "GroupRequired)
{
 throw NotAllowedException();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the security credentials of the calling user through the [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx).  This will be subject to your having made the service available on an endpoint using a secured binding such as netTcpBinding or WSHttpBinding.

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Groups
```

Comment: Where do I add this code?  In my wcf service library? e.g. if my method is GetData(), I will add this line inside GetData()?

Comment: also the group only has Guid value. how do I get the name of the group instead with the domain?